# Where is the isAjax() method in Play Framework 2.0?

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.0

In Play Framework 1.x, we could quickly know if the request was AJAX or not by asking `request.isAjax()` method, but I can't find it on Play 2.

What is the alternative or where is this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use JQuery for Ajax, it sets the following Request Header:

```
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

that you can later access to test if a call is done via Ajax or not.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I was just wondering if there was a similar method as `isAjax` directly in Play Fw, instead of having to check for this header every time I need to know.

Comment: No, there is none, you have to check the headers.

Comment: It's sad. Why did they removed this method, it was very useful?!

Comment: @cx42net well, can't speak for the devs, but I believe it's a non-standard header so it wouldn't work in all scenarios and would lead to a lot of confussion.

Comment: @cx42net how about creating a controller helper trait with methods like isAjax, i18n, str2Json and other common utility methods? We can bake our cake (and eat it too) in Scala ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can define it as a method and use it in your controller:

```
def isAjax[A](implicit request : Request[A]) = {
  request.headers.get("X-Requested-With") == Some("XMLHttpRequest")
}
```

Comment: +1, just checking for presence of x-requested-with header is not enough, Android 4 sends the header no matter what (as "com.google.android.browser"), ajax request or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naive Java implementation for those who don't use Scala (like me)

```
/**
 * Check if the request was made via Ajax or not
 * @return
 */
public static Boolean isAjax() {
    String requestWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
    String requestWithHeaderValueForAjax = "XMLHttpRequest";

    String[] value = request().headers().get(requestWithHeader);
    return
        value != null &&
        value.length > 0 &&
        value[0].equals(requestWithHeaderValueForAjax);
}
```